# monerod throws Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)

Tags: monerod, linux

I started `monerod` on my linux server to sync the (pruned) blockchain and start working with a wallet.

The syncing completed fine.
However trying to restart `monerod` the next day yielded the following error. How can I resolve it?

```
$ LANG=C LC_ALL=C  ./monerod --prune-blockchain
2021-05-01 07:56:27.451 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
2021-05-01 07:56:27.451 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2021-05-01 07:56:27.451 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2021-05-01 07:56:27.451 I Initializing core...
2021-05-01 07:56:27.452 I Loading blockchain from folder /home/deploy/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2021-05-01 07:56:27.529 I Loading checkpoints
2021-05-01 07:56:27.535 I Core initialized OK
2021-05-01 07:56:27.535 I Initializing p2p server...
2021-05-01 07:56:27.540 F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)
2021-05-01 07:56:27.540 I Deinitializing core...
2021-05-01 07:56:27.560 I Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2021-05-01 07:56:27.560 I Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2021-05-01 07:56:27.561 E Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have it running? `killall monerod` You can only run one daemon server process.

Comment: ok - without doing anything else, running `monerd` again now works. probably a stale process as you said.

Comment: Killall did not help me. When I look at the --log-level 4. It shows IPv4 trying to bind to ip 0.0.0.0:18080.
Could that be the issue? Thing is I can't change the ip it is trying to bind to unless monerod is active. I just get command not found. (p2p-bind-ip arg) Also what ip should I be using? The ip of another node to sync the blockchain or just the ip of the monerod-ws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is typically due to trying to start more that one daemon process or a previous process not exiting cleanly. Thus make absolutely sure there is no other `monerod` process running, such as running `killall monerod`, then trying to start again should fix the issue (or a reboot).

Comment: I had to use sudo

Answer (score 0):

Some cases kill all dosen't work so  use command ps -e | grep monero

it will display all process running with monero you need to kill all with there PID

like this
kill -9  PID

[image]

```
ps -e | grep monero
1021 ?        18:43:35 monerod
sudo kill -9 1021
```

Comment: `killall` kills alls processes matching name AND started by the current user. If you started monerod as root or some other user, you could have easily just ran `sudo killall monerod`.