# Using GUI wallet but when I check status in the log it says 0/0

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I have tried everything in these guides but still cannot seem to get my daemon to sync. It's just stuck at 0. When I type status in the log it says 0/0. Any suggestions? I'm using local node. I have plenty of space for the blockchain, it's on a 2TB drive. The daemon will not run. It gives an error saying Failed to bind to IPV4 (set to required). Then another error Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Also, do you run AV (AntiVirus) software?

Comment: "It gives an error saying Failed to bind to IPV4 (set to required)" -> See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12961/monerod-throws-error-starting-server-failed-to-bind-ipv4-set-to-required